# rails docker-compose bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, docker-compose

I have problem with my docker-compose on ruby on rails.
when i run

```
docker-compose run web bundle install
```

i have information that my gems installed succesfully, but when in next step i run

```
docker-compose up
```

then i have information that my container exited with code 1. I looked on docker logs and i get information that

```
Could not find gem XXXXXXXXX in any list of sources(Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

what is interesting i don't use this gem.

Moreover when i run bundle install outside container (on my local machine) everything works good. Where could be problem ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it.

What's your bundle version is running the container? You can check it at the last line in `Gemfile.lock` "BUNDLED WITH ...". (access with: `docker run -ti sfcr_web /bin/bash` and run `tail -n 2 Gemfile.lock`

Maybe your using a diferent gem version at the local machine/docker container.

You can do `gem uninstall xxxx` if you don't need that gem. Also it could be that your changes doesnt' take effect because your docker-compose is not using the last docker image, try:

1. `docker images`, check your previous images
2. `docker rmi your_image_name`
3. `docker container prune`, to delete your unused containers and start new ones.
4. `docker container up`

Comment: `docker container up` says it has no command `up`. `docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b`, `Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had `RUN gem update --system` inside my Dockerfile and this was installing the latest bundler (2.2.12 as of now), and setting it for use. I also had `RUN gem install bundler -v 2.2.2`, which was installing that version but it was not getting used. My Gemfile.lock had it on 2.2.2. This was a hard to debug bug, argh

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue.

The error was in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN gem update bundler
RUN bundle install
```

so the `gem update bundler` line should be removed :/